# how to solve the differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problems in solving the following differential equations, mainly I do not realize the type of equation:

$$ x'= \cos(t+x), $$ 
i have no information about  $t$
and i have the initial condition : x(0)=pi/2

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: This can be solved with a numerical method once you prescribe an initial condition.

Comment: but what type of equation is this?

Answer (score 3):

Using the substitution $u = t+x$ we have
$$
u' = x'+1.
$$
Substituting this in the equation, we have
$$
u' = 1+\cos u,
$$
which is a separable equation, leading to
$$
\int \frac{du}{1+\cos u} = C + \int dt.
$$
It should not be very difficult to show that, evaluating the integrals, on gets
$$
\tan \frac{u}{2} = t+C.
$$
Substituting back $u=t+x$ and manipulating the result, we have
$$
x = 2\arctan (t+C)-t.
$$
Applying the initial condition $x(0) = \pi/2$ leads to $C=\tan (\pi/4) = 1$. Then, the solution is
$$
x = 2\arctan (t+1)-t.
$$